# gnu screen not to change my window titles

Tags: linux, vim, title, gnu-screen

I set meaningful names to new windows I create in gnu screen, but then when I 'cd' or open vim that name gets changed to 'pwd' for instance. Is there a way to prevent screen from changing the title? I know there's a setting like that in tmux, but for some reason vim scrolls really slow in tmux with multiple vertical splits, so I had to abandon it (tmux). Ideas appreciated!

Comment: This is probably being done by your shell prompt. You have an escape sequence that's setting the window title, which `screen` obeys.

Comment: Anyway, this os not a programming question, it's off-topic here. Try superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: can you post your hardstatus string from .screenrc ?

Comment: @funtime I don't have a hardstatus string specified in .screenrc, it just uses the default '[screen %n%?: %t%] %h]' one.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to your `.screenrc` if you are using the latest version:

```
defdynamictitle off
```